# How to scrape data from Ajax or Json

Tags: php, json, ajax, curl, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from this [url](https://www.apwagner.com/appliance-part/wpl/wp661600)

I am able to fetch simple data from html tags usign curl but not able to fetch data from Json or Ajax, I am not sure is it Ajax or Json data.

In below screen shot I want to fetch **Appliance Models Data**.
[image]

Which is coming form I think json or ajax. ==>>

[image]

Here below is my script to get data from page -

```
$loginURL = "https://www.apwagner.com/appliance-part/wpl/wp661600";
//$file='source.html'; //create a html file to save source code
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Please provide some guidance to fetch this info ..

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.apwagner.com/Product/GetPartModel");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "partNumber=wp661600&make=wpl");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: have you looked at `DOMDocument`?? http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Yes, I have also checked that. But did not worked.

Comment: obviously that wont work directly,  that was just to help you out kick-start.. you'll have to create a code using as per your requirements...

Comment: @NishantSolanki I have tried using many ways .. can you please guide how can I get data using DOMDocument or any other way.

Comment: I checked the URL and the listing you are trying to access via CURL is not direclty loading .. It's coming through ajax... Get the ajax url.. check which data is passing in the URL, make a ajax call to same url with same data and you will get your results :D.. this answer can help you out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625915/is-there-a-way-to-let-curl-wait-until-the-pages-dynamic-updates-are-done

Answer (score 1):

The part of data page gets through ajax request.

[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD3Me.jpg)

You need to do it with curl 
after your first curl response is received

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.apwagner.com/Product/GetPartModel");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "partNumber=wp661600&make=wpl");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Or try to scrap data using python script

```
import string
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('<path to your chrome driver>') 
driver.get('https://www.apwagner.com/appliance-part/wpl/wp661600');
```