# cUrl waits for url to load IF results are printed

Tags: php, curl

The following `curl`-call succeeds every time, if and only if `$data` is printed after the `curl`-call. `curl_getinfo()` returning

`[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8`

If `$data` is not printed, the `curl`-call **sometimes** return the same result as above and **sometimes** returns `$data` being "Loading...", Which means that page has not finished loading yet. And `curl_getinfo()` returning

`[content_type] => text/html`

Furthermore, when using `print_r($data)`, I can see the `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` on my website being updated several times while performing the `curl`-call. What... The.... F?

(the `set_opt`-list has grown larger as I'm trying to find a solution LOL)
Ooh.. yeah, even if I print `$data` after it's been returned to function caller and caught in another variable.. `curl` succeeds every time.

Is this normal behaviour? I don't want to `print_r($data)`!

Is it possible that the url I'm retrieving contains javascript which gets run when I "print" it on my website? Why does it work occasionally without the `print_r($data)`? Ref: [is-there-a-way-to-let-curl-wait-until-the-pages-dynamic-updates-are-done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625915/is-there-a-way-to-let-curl-wait-until-the-pages-dynamic-updates-are-done)

edit: Until further notice, I've put the `curl`-call in a while-loop, checking if downloaded size is above a certain threshold. I've set the while loop to 10 iterations, and so far it is enough, i.e. it will manage to download the content of interest. Time consumed is barely noticed.

```
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    global $dbg;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($dbg) {
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); // This one gets refreshed if print_r($data) used below
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        } else {
            echo "ALL GOOD <br>";
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo $data;    // If I do this...
    //print_r($data); // ... or this. curl is success 100%.
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz added clarifying questions

Comment: No, that is not normal behaviour... how can curl return while the URL has not finished loading? It's not asynchron and I never heard of such behaviour before...

Comment: PHP cannot time travel. The success of an earlier operation cannot be dependent on what you do later.

Comment: I suspect the result you're seeing has to do with the HTML that's being retrieved from the remote site. Maybe it contains JavaScript that's being executed when you return it to the browser. Use View Source to see the raw results.

Comment: @Barmar, well I get that. Since I'm not all *high* on `curl` I figured it might have something to do with cache and/or similarities with enabledelayedexpansion in batch. "...time travel" - LMAO

Comment: can you replicate this behaviour in a fiddle?

Comment: Most likely the 30 second timeout isn't enough.

Comment: @Forbs it is. Never has the page taken more than 3 seconds to load.. with or without the `print_r`